# Javascript TypeError: null is not an object when saving contents of div element to a text file

Tags: javascript, html, text, null, txt

I am trying to save the contents of a div element to a text file and get the error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'link.href =
> generateTxtFile('dummyText.innerText')')

What is the problem here? I have made sure to put the dive elements before the Javascript code.

[The whole project.](http://m.uploadedit.com/busd/1604344229948.txt)

Thanks

```js
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      function generateTxtFile(text){
        var textFile = null;
        var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
        if (textFile !== null) {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
        }
        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        return textFile;
      }
      (function () {
        var btnCreateFile = document.getElementById('btnCreateFile'),
        dummyText = document.getElementById('log');
        btnCreateFile.addEventListener('click', function () {
          var link = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
          link.href = generateTxtFile('dummyText.innerText');
          link.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }, false);
      })();
    }
    }
                              )
```

```html
        <button id="btnCreateFile">Generate File</button>
    <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
         <div id="log">
              <span>Log</span>
              <br>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
              <p>----------------</p>
              <br>
              </div>
```

Comment: `if (textFile !== null) {` will never evaluate to true, because you declare the variable as null two lines before. You need to delcare `textFile` outside the function. The error occurs because `link` is null. Likely the anchor does not exist when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo..  you have `id="downloadlink` in the html,
But you're doing `var link = document.getElementById('downloadLink');`

Notice the capital L... Change the html to  `downloadLink` and `link` should not be null...